# Is it possible to use .NET (not C# Script) for Azure Bot Service?

Tags: .net, botframework, azure-bot-service

For now Bot Service template for LUIS creates `run.csx` and `BasicLuisDialog.csx`. But their structure does not allow to build anything bigger than simple demos. For example you have to define all LUIS intents in one class as methods. Another problem C# script does not allow namespaces making it hard to use for anything big.

And so there is way to use .NET dlls but that makes dependencies managing just horrible. I tried to include all dlls from project implementing my own IDialog and any logic above. I changed `run.csx` to use my IDialog implementation loaded by `#r` but then I get error

`mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.messages. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. f-messages__-1289066319: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotAuthenticator Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.BotService.get_Authenticator()'`

Playing with dependencies in project.json (which is by the way outdated for .NET) I get just another error

`mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.messages. f-messages__-213535778: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Tried to find any example of Bot Service and .NET integration but nothing.

Comment: Have a look at the [BotBuilder SDK for .NET overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-overview)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using botbuilder in VS rather than the bot service.  There is a template for VS that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart).

Comment: Bot  written with Bot Builder is not compatible with Azure Bot Service. So this is not an answer.

Comment: You can deploy it as an app service in Azure rather than bot service.  but you can also write you bot in Node.js in bot service if you like.

Comment: That's not related to the question. App service is much much more expensive especially if bot is used only several times per day. Bot Service is paid only per message processing.